# Getting two errors E0289 and C2440 pointing at initialization of vector

Tags: vector, constructor, initialization

I am getting these two errors when initializing vc below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <math>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>
#include <list>
#include <string>

class Vector {
private:
    double* elem; // elem points to an array of sz doubles
    int sz;
public:
    
            Vector(int s) :elem{ new double [s] }, sz{ s } // constructor: acquire resources
    {
        for (int i = 0; i != s; ++i) elem[i] = 0; // initialize elements
    
~Vector() { delete[] elem; } // destructor: release resources
    double& operator[](int i);
    int size() const;
    void push_back(double);


    };

double& Vector::operator[](int i)
{
    // TODO: insert return statement here
    // added below since the funtion needs to return a double and 
    return elem[i];

}

int Vector::size() const
{
    return sz;
}


void Vector::push_back(double)
{
}

class Container {
public:
virtual double& operator[](int) = 0; // pure virtual function
virtual int size() const = 0; // const member function (§3.2.1.1)
virtual ~Container() {} // destructor (§3.2.1.2)
};
// use function uses Container interface. 
void use(Container& c)
{
const int sz = c.size();
for (int i=0; i!=sz; ++i)
cout << c[i] << '\n';
}

class Vector_container : public Container { // List_container implements Container
    Vector v;

public:
    Vector_container(int s) : v(s) {} // Vector of s elements
    void ˜Vector_container() {}
    double& operator[](int i) { return v[i]; }
    int size() const { return v.size(); }

    
};


void main()

{
    Vector_container vc = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    use(vc)

}
```

I receive both errors pointing at this line  Vector_container vc = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }

Error E0289 is - no instance of constructor "Vector_container::Vector_container" matches the argument list
Error   C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'Vector_container'

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by modifying the Vector_container and initializing using Initializer-list constructor below:

```
class Vector_container : public Container { 
    
    std::list<double> ld;

public:

    Vector_container() { } 
    Vector_container(initializer_list<double> il) : ld{ il } {}
    ~Vector_container() {}
    double& operator[](int i);
    int size() const { return ld.size(); }
    
};

double& Vector_container::operator[](int i)
{
    for (auto& x : ld) {
        if (i == 0) return x;
        --i;
    }
    
}
```